# Log4J Override Properties in Sub-Project

Tags: maven, logging, log4j, dependencies, hierarchy

The question:
How can I override log4j.properties in a maven module that has a dependency on a module that sets log4j.properties?

Description of problem:

I have a project that's comprises a web app and a jar that executes daily tasks.
Recently I wished to have logging to different files for each of them.

They BOTH use a common jar that contains DAO connectivity, Helper Classes etc.
log4J is included in the common module as logging takes place there, together with the other modules that depend on the common module.

I'm using maven to compile and package all three modules (common, webApp, nightlyTasks).

All module use a common maven settings.xml file containing:

```
<logging.folder>W:/WorkEnv/logs</logging.folder>
<logging.file>cars.log</logging.file>
<nightly.logging.file>carsNightly.log</nightly.logging.file>
```

In the common module I have the following:

in pom.xml:

```
  <!--Logging-->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
```

in log4j.properties:

```
log=${logging.folder}
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/${logging.file}
```

Everything works fine - all logging performed by the common and web app module go to W:/WorkEnv/logs/cars.log

In the carsNighly module I include the dependency on the common module:

```
    <!-- carsCommon -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alton.cars</groupId>
        <artifactId>carsCommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

and in the carsNightly I also include a log4j.properties file that contains this in it's entirety:

```
#Use properties in jobsCommon and override here

log=${logging.folder}
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/${nightly.logging.file}
```

(even though logging.folder is the same, I've included it because it's referenced on the next line however the result is the same either way)

However, the carsNightly module does not log to the different file - it's output is placed in cars.log

So to ask again:
How can I override log4j.properties in a maven module that has a dependency on a module that sets log4j.properties?  i.e. How can I set log4j.properties in the carsNightly module that are a different value for the same property in the common module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have carsNightly/src/main/resources/log4j.properties and common/src/main/resources/log4j.properties , each module will use its  log4j.properties